Search facility in Magneto 2 checkout crashes checkout
We are using M2 2.4.4-p3 and when a user has a number of addresses in there address book at checkout when searching it crashes the checkout and throws a down for maintenance page..
Has anyone else had issues with searching 20+ addresses? Does anyone use any extensions for searching at checkout that they can recommend?
